# new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell") is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, activexobject

I'm trying to create an `ActiveXObject("WScript.shell")` in Internet Explorer (Version 11). But when I use the command `new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell")` it is returning undefined object. How to resolve this error?

Comment: Is this an intranet app?

Comment: No... an internet app

Comment: Set the security level to zero in IE's Internet options | Security | Internet Zone, though you could throw your machine out of the window as well as allow execution of ActiveX via internet.